# Private bytes in an native assembly

Tags: .net, ngen

I have an application that is ran on a Citrix farm.  On a single server you may have 4-10 instances of this application running at any one time.  The application is downloaded via click-once so currently the assemblies are not shared.

I am trying to reduce the memory footprint and so am experimenting with putting these assemblies in the GAC and NGEN'ing them.  I wrote a test client that references a DLL that has a million generated classes with a single method on it.  The code to generate the classes is below:

```
class Program
{
    private const string ClassFormat =
        @"public class AutoGen{0}
        {{
            public void Do()
            {{
               Console.WriteLine();
            }}
        }}";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(@"Classes.cs", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine("using System;");
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine(ClassFormat, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The .NET assembly is 82,928 K and it has 0 private bytes when viewed with VMMap.  I have NGEN'd the DLL and see that it is 304,724 K and that it has 195,096 K of it being private.  I also see that the process loads both the managed and native DLLs.

Why does it load both DLLs and why isn't it 100% shareable?

Comment: The CLR must load the regular dll first to have access to the metadata and to discover the ni.dll file.  The msil in the regular dll will never be used and is never read from the file or mapped into memory.  It still occupies virtual memory space, that don't cost anything.  It is virtual.  Numbers you see in VMMap are only weakly correlated to runtime cost.

Comment: @HansPassant if there is private memory in the NI section that must have been *made* private by some writing to it. That causes runtime memory usage.

Comment: @HansPassant, that makes sense and correlates to the fact that only 28 K of the 82,928 K is in the working set.  Any idea about all the private bytes?  My best guess is it is caused by rebasing but that seems like a large number.  But it is 1 million classes, going to make 1 class with 1 million statements to see if that is different.